# To match the attribute value from two different xml and replace the text using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

To match the attribute value from two different xml files and replace the text
1. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hostids>
   <hostid id="001">Agent</hostid>
   <hostid id="002">test2</hostid>
</hostids>
```

2. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
   <resource>
      <host id="001">jaffar 123</host>
   </resource>
   <resource>
      <host id="002">school 234</host>
   </resource>
</resources>
```

Output: I need

```
<hostids>
   <hostid id="001">jaffar 123</hostid>
   <hostid id="002">school 234</hostid>
</hostids>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="ref" match="resource/host" use="@id"/>`, then write a template that checks whether a cross-reference exists and replace the contents, in XSLT 3 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="hostid[key('ref', @id, $doc2)]/text()">{key('ref', ../@id, $doc2)}</xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 2 you need

```
<xsl:template match="hostid[key('ref', @id, $doc2)]/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', ../@id, $doc2)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT 3 sample online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2r is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:param name="doc2">
    <resources>
       <resource>
          <host id="001">jaffar 123</host>
       </resource>
       <resource>
          <host id="002">school 234</host>
       </resource>
    </resources>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="ref" match="resource/host" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="hostid[key('ref', @id, $doc2)]/text()">{key('ref', ../@id, $doc2)}</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

obviously you could use `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('file2.xml')"/>` to read the second document from another file.